# Change a string = '1 1/4' to '1.2500'

Tags: sql-server

`declare @Dimension = '1 1/4' varchar(20)`

I want to change `Dimension = '1 1/4'` to `Dimension = '1.2500'`. I do not know how to split 
a varchar into 2 varchar and change one part and then recombine then into a single varchar

```
UPDATE VF_CasINV_Cost
   SET @Dimension = CASE

        when (@Dimension like '%1/4') then
        (left(@Dimension, charindex(' ', @Dimension, 1) - 1) *
        (substring(@Dimension, 1 + charindex(' ', @Dimension, 1), len(@Dimension)))

           end
where @Dimension like '%1/4'
```

what would be great to know how to parse the fraction and recal it into decimal on the fly

Comment: SQL Server is pretty bad at string parsing. Which version are you using? Is a CLR solution possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @x varchar(100)
select @x = '15 3/165'
select 
    convert(int, substring(@x, 1, charindex(' ', @x))) + (
        convert(decimal(12,4), substring(@x, charindex(' ', @x) + 1, charindex('/', @x) - charindex(' ', @x) - 1)) /
        convert(decimal(12,4), substring(@x, charindex('/', @x) + 1, len(@x) - charindex('/', @x)))
    )
```

Comment: pretty well what i would have come up with

Comment: a problem with this solution is that it would make @x = '15' invalid

Answer (score 1):

**Payload** beat me to it but one way is to;

```
declare @Dimension varchar(20) = '1 1/8' 
declare @sql nvarchar(512) = 'set @out=' + replace(@Dimension, ' ',' + ') + '.00'
declare @result decimal(9,4)

execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@value varchar(30), @out decimal(9,4) output', @value=@Dimension, @out=@result output
select @result
```

Answer (score 0):

isolate the fraction with substring and charindexing, then execute a select.

```
set @stringquery = SELECT "SELECT "+substring(@Dimension,1+charindex(' ',@Dimension,1),len(@Dimension);
execute sp_executesql @stringquery
```

This should handle and fraction after a space.

actually, thinking about it - to do the whole equation, just replace the space with a + sign and run it through sp_executesql, this should (I havnt tested this right at this point) convert 1 1/4 to 1+1/4 and the standard math engine will do the division before the addition so it will end up as 1.25.

Comment: The concept of your answer would work, but there are couple of things to note. First, if you just process 1/4 in sql server it will attempt to do integer division and return 0. 1.0/4.0 would give you the .25 you are looking for or it will work if you force a conversion to float in some other way.  Also, while you can use sp_executesql this way, letting it parse arbitrary strings like that does risk opening up a vector for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

This script can handle more variations in dimension (x in the table)

```
declare @t table(x varchar(20))
insert @t values('1 1/2')
insert @t values('2')
insert @t values('2/3')
insert @t values('22 1/3')


select coalesce(cast(case when isnumeric(n1)=1 then n1 else 0 end + n2 / n3 as real), n1)
from
(
select case when isnumeric(x) = 1 then x else 
left(x, patindex('%_ %', x)) end n1, 
cast(stuff(stuff(x, patindex('%/%', x), charindex('/',reverse(x)), ''), 1,charindex(' ',x),'') as real) n2,
case when patindex('%_/%', reverse(x)) = 0 then null else 
cast(right(x, patindex('%_/%', reverse(x))) as real) end n3
from @t
) a
```